# Seaborn and plotly violin plots in Jupyter Notebook kill kernel

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, violin-plot

I am trying to generate a violin plot using seaborn 0.7.1 in a Jupyter notebook. Boxplot works fine for the same data, but violinplot causes the kernel to "die unexpectedly."

I have also tried using plotly 1.12.9 to do a violin plot (following the example on the plotly website), but that also kills the kernel.

Does anyone have any idea about what the error might be or how I should go about debugging this?

This is the code I used for seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(x="Group", y="Data", data=df, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylim([0., 1.])
fig2.title = "Data by Group"
fig2.show()
```

and this is the code I use for plotly:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF
from plotly.graph_objs import graph_objs
from scipy import stats

fig = FF.create_violin(bs_df, data_header="Data", group_header="Group",
                           height=500, width=800)
fig.show()
```

The error that Jupyter Notebook wasn't showing was:

`Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so.`

Comment: it's going to be hard to troubleshoot this without a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error message below:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so.
```

I was able to resolve it by updating numpy to 1.11.1 and scipy to 0.17.1.